# Invalid Null Pointer in user-defined Class?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

everyone. This is my first time using classes in C++. The instructions in the assignment I'm working on seemed a little ambiguous to me, so I'm including them in case someone more experienced thinks I'm not following them properly in my code.

Anyway, I wrote my program, and it works and creates the output I want based on my perception of the assignment. However, when I run it, an error also pops up that says "Invalid Null Pointer." I've done some research but I can't seem to figure out why this is.

Can someone help me fix my code and help a student understand what they did wrong? Thanks! :)

**Assignment**

> Write a Person class that contains the following fields and methods:
>
> • First Name
>   • Last Name
>   • ID Number
>   • Necessary constructors
>   •
>   Methods to return last name, first name, full name, and ID number
>   •
>   Methods to print last name, first name, and ID number
>
> Write a main program to test your class.

**My Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {
private:
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    string FullName;
    int IDNumber;
public:
    void SetFirstName(string);
    void SetLastName(string);
    void SetIDNumber(int);
    string SetFullName(string first, string last);
    string GetFirstName();
    string GetLastName();
    string Method1();
    string Method2();
    int GetIDNumber();
};

void Person::SetFirstName(string first) {
    FirstName = first;
}

void Person::SetLastName(string last) {
    LastName = last;
}

void Person::SetIDNumber(int ID) {
    IDNumber = ID;
}

string Person::SetFullName(string first, string last) {
    FullName = string(first + " " + last);
    return FullName;
}

string Person::GetFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

string Person::GetLastName() {
    return LastName;
}


int Person::GetIDNumber() {
    return IDNumber;
}

string Person::Method1() {
    cout << "LAST NAME: " << LastName << endl;
    cout << "FIRST NAME: " << FirstName << endl;
    cout << "FULL NAME: " << FullName << endl;
    cout << "ID NUMBER: " << IDNumber << endl;
    return 0;
}

string Person::Method2() {
    cout << "LAST NAME: " << LastName << endl;
    cout << "FIRST NAME: " << FirstName << endl;;
    cout << "ID NUMBER: " << IDNumber << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    string firstname, lastname;
    int id;
    char command;
    Person Person;
    cout << "What is the subject's first name? For example: Bob Smith" << endl;
    cin >> firstname >> lastname;
    cout << "What is " << firstname << " " << lastname << "'s ID number?" << endl;
    cin >> id;
    Person.SetFirstName(firstname);
    Person.SetLastName(lastname);
    string fullname = Person.SetFullName(firstname, lastname);
    Person.SetIDNumber(id);
    cout << "COMMANDS:" << endl;
    cout << "f : Returns first name." << endl << "l : Returns last name." << endl << "i : returns ID number." << endl << "n : returns full name." << endl;
    cout << "1 : Returns last name, first name, full name, and ID number." << endl;
    cout << "2 : Returns last name, first name, and ID number." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please input the letter of your command: ";
    cin >> command;
    switch (command) {
    case 'f':
    case 'F':
        cout << "FIRST NAME: " << Person.GetFirstName() << endl;;
        break;
    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        cout << "LAST NAME: " << Person.GetLastName() << endl;
        break;
    case 'i':
    case 'I':
        cout << "ID NUMBER: " << Person.GetIDNumber() << endl;
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        cout << "FULL NAME: " << fullname << endl;
        break;
    case '1':
        Person.Method1();
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case '2':
        Person.Method2();
        cout << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "That is not a valid command." << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string Person::Method1() {

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

There's your problem.

Your method returns a `std::string`.  0, in this context, is treated as a `NULL` pointer, and your code blows up attempting to convert a `NULL` pointer into a string.

P.S. If you used a debugger to step through your code, a line at a time, you would've been able to figure it out yourself, instead of asking strangers on `stackoverflow.com` for help. Learning how to use a debugger is a required skill for every `C++` developer.